# Elasticsearch check if title is already used in type

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-query

I've collected a database in Elasticsearch and I didn't identify them by ID, but rather by the title. Therefore no titles are the same in each type.

I tried having `must => match_phrase` but it got me more than one in return. Something might be called `"Document 1"` and something else might be called `"Document 1,2,3"`. Therefore it would return more than one result by doing `match_phrase`.

Let's say I have 5 documents named:

1. Document example 1
2. Example 1
3. 1 Document example
4. Document example 1 and 2
5. Document example

What request should I send to only return for example: `"Document example"`?

I tried different variations of this kind of search to `127.0.0.1:9200/index/type/_search`:

```
{
    "query":{
        "match_phrase": {
            "title":"Document example"
        }
    }
}
```

So I was wondering about how I could check or search the exact parse and get only one or zero results in return?

**EDIT**

`127.0.0.1:9200/myindex/mytype/_mapping` returns this:

```
{
  "myindex": {
    "mappings": {
      "mytype": {
        "properties": {
          "category": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "date": {
            "type": "date"
          },
          "link": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "size": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "source": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "title": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share mapping of your index. `GET /index/type/_mapping`.

Comment: Also, you need to define better your requirements. Asking for a query for getting back only `"Document example"` is easy. The questions also are: what if you search for `document example`? Do you have other queries that should match your `title` field? Are you interested in partial matching as well?

Comment: @Richa I added it at the bottom. I changed some of its values (Index and type)

Comment: @AndreiStefan Database contains lower and uppercase. In this case, there is no duplicates even if it is upper or lowercase. I should maybe have explained that in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a `term` filter (which does **exact** matching) on `title.keyword`:

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "title.keyword": {
        "value": "Document example"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow, Beautiful. Worked!